# Render adonis view in React

Tags: reactjs, adonis.js

The views in Adonis are in Nunjucks(.njk) format. I don't want to use this rather use React to render my views. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a route that handle any request to "launch" your SPA ([Routes For SPA’s](http://adonisjs.com/docs/3.1/routing#_routes_for_spa_s)). Then your only view will launch your React application.

Answer (score 1):

In your adonis root file, you need to create a folder any name you want like "client" then in that folder you will install your react app. then in package.json just add a proxy to request api's in your root/domain name to call your adonis backend. Hope it helps.